# Ruby Array Intersection, Hash.has_value? for intersection with array[i+1] based on hash values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, intersection

I am trying to populate an array with an intersection of an array and hash based on hash values:

```
array2 = ["hi","world","One"]
VALS = {:one => "One", :two => "Two"}
array2 = VALS.values & array2
print array2
```

Works fine for intersection of hash values and `array2[i]`, but if I want to instead populate with `array2[i+1]` element from `array2`, I am lost.

Also tried:

```
array2.select { |i| VALS.has_value? i ? array2[i+1] : nil }
```

But no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed title, `Array#&` is intersection and *not* a bitwise &.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = []
array2.each_with_index{|v,i| array << (VALS.has_value? i ?  array2[i+1] : nil)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're trying to treat your array as a series of either internal keys and values, or external keys into the inverse of vals. So the correct result from your example would be:

```
{"hi" => "World", "One" => :one}
```

Is that right? If so, here:

```
invertedvals = vals.invert
Hash[*array2.map {|x| [x,invertedvals[x]]}.flatten.compact]
```

If not, please clarify what result you're trying to produce...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with as an answer to my own question:

```
array1.each do |i|
   puts "#"*5 + i + "#"*5 if !array2.include? i
  if array2.include? i
    result << i+":" << array2[array2.index(i)+1]
  end
end
```

Is there a speedier algorithm for this? Would like to use:

```
array1 & array2
```

Also used inject at one point, benchmark showed very little difference between any of them.